Create new column based on multiple columns and some conditions
I have a data frame with 2-level indexed columns (sample data below):
  metric         grp        Avg                              P95                     
                           mean     ci_low      ci_up       mean     ci_low      ci_up
0      a     CONTROL   8.202862   8.100596   8.306985  17.122063  16.832979  17.400000
1      a  EXPERIMENT   8.243680   8.141428   8.351050  16.709375  16.383333  17.043500
2      a        diff   0.040819  -0.102122   0.185837  -0.412688  -0.855854   0.050104
3      a    rel_diff   0.005016  -0.012299   0.022944  -0.024022  -0.049377   0.002982
4      b     CONTROL  15.513669  15.316762  15.720606  31.893576  31.357300  32.600350
5      b  EXPERIMENT  15.486001  15.293760  15.672843  31.317389  30.808775  31.839000
6      b        diff  -0.027668  -0.300167   0.251497  -0.576186  -1.450138   0.223063
7      b    rel_diff  -0.001740  -0.019249   0.016368  -0.017967  -0.044785   0.007031  

Result I'd like to produce:

create a new column in format of mean [cl_low, cl_up] for each level-1 column Avg, P95
for rel_diff rows, reformat all columns as percentages, e.g.: 0.005016 --> 0.5%.
for rest rows, round all columns to 3rd digit

What is the pythonic way to do this? Thanks in advance for tips!

If your example sample has a multi-index, please provide the code to generate your sample. Sample data is not only provided for reference, it is provided for reproduction.

You simply need to do the following:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    ('metric', ''): ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    ('grp', ''): ['CONTROL', 'EXPERIMENT', 'diff', 'rel_diff', 'CONTROL', 'EXPERIMENT', 'diff', 'rel_diff'],
    ('Avg', 'mean'): [8.202862, 8.243680, 0.040819, 0.005016, 15.513669, 15.486001, -0.027668, -0.001740],
    ('Avg', 'ci_low'): [8.100596, 8.141428, -0.102122, -0.012299, 15.316762, 15.293760, -0.300167, -0.019249],
    ('Avg', 'ci_up'): [8.306985, 8.351050, 0.185837, 0.022944, 15.720606, 15.672843, 0.251497, 0.016368],
    ('P95', 'mean'): [17.122063, 16.709375, -0.412688, -0.024022, 31.893576, 31.317389, -0.576186, -0.017967],
    ('P95', 'ci_low'): [16.832979, 16.383333, -0.855854, -0.049377, 31.357300, 30.808775, -1.450138, -0.044785],
    ('P95', 'ci_up'): [17.400000, 17.043500, 0.050104, 0.002982, 32.600350, 31.839000, 0.223063, 0.007031],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

numeric_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col[1] in ['mean', 'ci_low', 'ci_up']]
df[numeric_cols] = df[numeric_cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

df.loc[df[('grp', '')] == 'rel_diff', numeric_cols] = df.loc[df[('grp', '')] == 'rel_diff', numeric_cols].applymap(
    lambda x: f"{x * 100:.2f}%" if pd.notnull(x) else x
)

print(df)


which gives you
 metric         grp        Avg                              P95             \
                           mean     ci_low      ci_up       mean     ci_low   
0      a     CONTROL   8.202862   8.100596   8.306985  17.122063  16.832979   
1      a  EXPERIMENT    8.24368   8.141428    8.35105  16.709375  16.383333   
2      a        diff   0.040819  -0.102122   0.185837  -0.412688  -0.855854   
3      a    rel_diff      0.50%     -1.23%      2.29%     -2.40%     -4.94%   
4      b     CONTROL  15.513669  15.316762  15.720606  31.893576    31.3573   
5      b  EXPERIMENT  15.486001   15.29376  15.672843  31.317389  30.808775   
6      b        diff  -0.027668  -0.300167   0.251497  -0.576186  -1.450138   
7      b    rel_diff     -0.17%     -1.92%      1.64%     -1.80%     -4.48%   

             
      ci_up  
0      17.4  
1   17.0435  
2  0.050104  
3     0.30%  
4  32.60035  
5    31.839  
6  0.223063  
7     0.70%  

 UPDate: Answer to commetn 
To add a new string column to combine mean, ci_low, ci_up into one in format of mean [ci_low, ci_up] do this:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    ('metric', ''): ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    ('grp', ''): ['CONTROL', 'EXPERIMENT', 'diff', 'rel_diff', 'CONTROL', 'EXPERIMENT', 'diff', 'rel_diff'],
    ('Avg', 'mean'): [8.202862, 8.243680, 0.040819, 0.005016, 15.513669, 15.486001, -0.027668, -0.001740],
    ('Avg', 'ci_low'): [8.100596, 8.141428, -0.102122, -0.012299, 15.316762, 15.293760, -0.300167, -0.019249],
    ('Avg', 'ci_up'): [8.306985, 8.351050, 0.185837, 0.022944, 15.720606, 15.672843, 0.251497, 0.016368],
    ('P95', 'mean'): [17.122063, 16.709375, -0.412688, -0.024022, 31.893576, 31.317389, -0.576186, -0.017967],
    ('P95', 'ci_low'): [16.832979, 16.383333, -0.855854, -0.049377, 31.357300, 30.808775, -1.450138, -0.044785],
    ('P95', 'ci_up'): [17.400000, 17.043500, 0.050104, 0.002982, 32.600350, 31.839000, 0.223063, 0.007031],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for metric in ['Avg', 'P95']:
    mean_col = (metric, 'mean')
    ci_low_col = (metric, 'ci_low')
    ci_up_col = (metric, 'ci_up')

    df[(metric, 'summary')] = df.apply(lambda x: f"{x[mean_col]:.2f}% [{x[ci_low_col]:.2f}%, {x[ci_up_col]:.2f}%]" 
                                       if x[('grp', '')] == 'rel_diff' 
                                       else f"{x[mean_col]:.2f} [{x[ci_low_col]:.2f}, {x[ci_up_col]:.2f}]", axis=1)

print(df)

which gives
  metric         grp        Avg                              P95             \
                           mean     ci_low      ci_up       mean     ci_low   
0      a     CONTROL   8.202862   8.100596   8.306985  17.122063  16.832979   
1      a  EXPERIMENT   8.243680   8.141428   8.351050  16.709375  16.383333   
2      a        diff   0.040819  -0.102122   0.185837  -0.412688  -0.855854   
3      a    rel_diff   0.005016  -0.012299   0.022944  -0.024022  -0.049377   
4      b     CONTROL  15.513669  15.316762  15.720606  31.893576  31.357300   
5      b  EXPERIMENT  15.486001  15.293760  15.672843  31.317389  30.808775   
6      b        diff  -0.027668  -0.300167   0.251497  -0.576186  -1.450138   
7      b    rel_diff  -0.001740  -0.019249   0.016368  -0.017967  -0.044785   

                                 Avg                     P95  
       ci_up                 summary                 summary  
0  17.400000       8.20 [8.10, 8.31]    17.12 [16.83, 17.40]  
1  17.043500       8.24 [8.14, 8.35]    16.71 [16.38, 17.04]  
2   0.050104      0.04 [-0.10, 0.19]     -0.41 [-0.86, 0.05]  
3   0.002982   0.01% [-0.01%, 0.02%]  -0.02% [-0.05%, 0.00%]  
4  32.600350    15.51 [15.32, 15.72]    31.89 [31.36, 32.60]  
5  31.839000    15.49 [15.29, 15.67]    31.32 [30.81, 31.84]  
6   0.223063     -0.03 [-0.30, 0.25]     -0.58 [-1.45, 0.22]  
7   0.007031  -0.00% [-0.02%, 0.02%]  -0.02% [-0.04%, 0.01%]  


looks great. thank you! And how to create a new string column to combine mean, ci_low, ci_up into one in format of mean [ci_low, ci_up], e.g. 0.50% [-1.23%, 2.29%] and do this for both Avg and P95? this is where I struggled most.
